# Creating dynamic names

Tags: variables, fortran, iteration, fortran90

Is it possible to create dynamic variable names in fortran? (ft1,ft2,ft3 are being read from file input and all are same).(deg = 10 as of now).

I am giving snippet here as well :

```
call RKUTTA(h,TX,X,Y,ft1,ft2,ft3,kglobal,cglobal,invmass,Xout1,Yout1)

write(20,*) " TIME STEP VALUES  "  
write(20,*) "     Xout1   Yout1  "

do num = 1,deg
write(20,'(30f20.5)') Xout(deg)  , Yout(deg)  
end do
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I need to create ft1 to ftn (any number) is it possible to loop or create it dynamically without variable definition?
2. In the above subroutine ft1,ft2,ft3 are used as inputs to get the output Xout and Yout. The subroutine has to be called again with a different set of inputs to get a different output.

   ```
   call RKUTTA(h,TX,Xout1,Yout1,ft4,ft5,ft6,kglobal,cglobal,invmass,Xout2,Yout2)

   write(20,*) " TIME STEP VALUES  "  
   write(20,*) "     Xout2   Yout2  "

   do num = 1,deg
   write(20,'(30f20.5)') Xout2(deg)  , Yout2(deg)
   ```

Similarly the ft4,ft5,ft6... will expand to ftn,ftn+1,ftn+2 to get Xoutn and Youtn.

Hope you have understood my question. If not please bear with me and ask me for anything that needs to be changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

Use an array to hold the values of ft1 ... ftn and similar variables.